# Can i request SQL Server to cache a certain result set?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, caching

There is a certain query that is being called from an ASP .NET page. I studied the execution plan of that query in Management Studio and 87% is for a sort. I badly need the sorting or else the data displayed would be meaningless.

Is there anyway that I can request SQL Server to cache a sorted results set so it will return the data faster in consequent runs?

Or is SQL Server smart enough to do the cache handling and am I doing mistake by trying to force it to cache results, if that is possible?

Any relevant information will be highly appreciated and thanks a lot in advance :)

**UPDATE:**
I just read in an article that creating a View with a clustered index will increase performance because the index will persist the data in a view to disk. Is this true? How do i get about doing this? Any articles?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In short, no: not at the SQL server end; it will of course load the data into memory if possible, and cache the *execution plan* - so subsequent calls may be *faster*, but it can't cache the results.

Options:

- tune the plan; the sort sounds aggressive - could you perhaps denormalize some data or add an index (perhaps even a clustered index); there may be other things we can do with the query if you show it (but tuning without a fully working DB is guestimation at best)
- cache the results *at the web-server* if it is sensible to do so

Answer (score 16):

Whilst you *can* create an [indexed view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx), as you allude to in your update, you should be aware that:

1. There are quite a lot of rules you have to follow, both when creating the view, and when updating the tables upon which it is based, and,
2. Just because there's a (clustered) index, that doesn't imply a sort order - you would still have to use an ORDER BY when querying this table, and,
3. Unless you're using Enterprise edition, you have to query the view with the WITH (NOEXPAND) [query hint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx)
4. You would specify the order for the index by specifying ASC and DESC in the CREATE INDEX statement, not in the CREATE VIEW. The "hack" to allow ORDER BY in a view (by specicfying top 100 percent) would have no effect.

Answer (score 2):

An option that is used sometimes is to store the sorted data in a secondary table. This could e.g. be a temporary table which you create for just the session, or a cache table for the entire database.

Answer (score 2):

Again, SQL server itself will cache frequent queries in memory.  You can test this by using query analyzer and running a complex query a few times,  each time it will get faster.  Given this a permanent cache might not be necessary.

If it is I recommend using a cache table and running your query and inserting the values into the other table.   You can either use a application variable or another sql table to determine when to refresh the cache again.

Example query for inserting into the cache table:

Insert Into Cache Select Value, Value from Table 1 Order by Field