# Is there a microsoft SQL query result cache equivalent?

Tags: sql, sql-server, caching

I'm working with a tool that shows some counts from a table in a UI.
To get those numbers a singe query is executed every 5 seconds. I cannot make any structural changes in the tool, but I am able to change the query the gets the counts.

The problem is that the execution of the query can take up to 5 seconds, in wich the user can't do anything. The data that the query is fetching only changes like every few minutes.

The tool can run both on Oracle and MSSQL. In Oracle I was able to greatly improve the speed of the query by using the query result cache (added the /*+ RESULT_CACHE */ hint to the query). Since the result of the query only changes every now and then, caching it is a usable solution in this specific case. The executing time goes to something like 1ms instead of the 5 secodns it was before.

I was wondering if there is a equivalent in Microsoft SQL.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Management Studio has the ability to show a query execution plan that shows the percentage of time spent on each part of a query. From the Query menu, investigate the "Display estimated execution plan" and "Include actual execution plan" menu items.

There's also a SQL Server query plan cache:

```
-- First, clear the cache.
-- WARNING: Do not execute this statement anywhere near production!
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE

-- Look at what executable plans are in cache
SELECT sc.*
FROM master.dbo.syscacheobjects AS sc
WHERE sc.cacheobjtype = 'Executable Plan'

-- Execute the following statement
SELECT t.*
FROM pubs.dbo.titles AS t
WHERE t.price = 19.99

-- Look at what executable plans are in cache and you'll 
-- find that there's a plan for a NUMERIC(4,2)
SELECT sc.*
FROM master.dbo.syscacheobjects AS sc
WHERE sc.cacheobjtype = 'Executable Plan'

-- If you execute the EXACT same statement with a 4,2 
-- then you will get THAT plan. But if you execute with a 5,2
-- then you'll get a new plan. Try this:
SELECT t.*
FROM pubs.dbo.titles AS t
WHERE price = 199.99

-- Look again at the cached executable plans, and you'll see a NEW one...
SELECT sc.*
FROM master.dbo.syscacheobjects AS sc
WHERE sc.cacheobjtype = 'Executable Plan'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it's what I was looking for. The query that is executed will deleiver the same result in lets say 29 out of 30 executions. Because of that it would be nice if SQL server could cache the result of the query, not the execution plan like you can in oracle.

I would however be happy with any improvement, but querying master.dbo.syscacheobjects give me no rows at all.

Comment: @ErikL, please see the answers to this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095762/can-i-request-sql-server-to-cache-a-certain-result-set